# Avro file error while loading decimal field into Redshift table using Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, avro, databricks

I have a dataframe in Databricks, which has bunch of columns including a decimal(15,2) field.  If I exclude the decimal field then I am able to insert this data into the Redshift table, but when decimal field is included then I get following error:
**"Cannot init avro reader from s3 file Cannot parse file header: Cannot save fixed schema"**
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use just `decimal` without range. Or cast existing column to `decimal`. Also try to use different `tempformat`. From my experience `CSV GZIP` is faster.

Comment: If I cast it to decimal without range, it is defaulting to decimal(10,0), but data is (12,2) so there will be loss of data.

Comment: Yes, changing format to 'CSV GZIP' has worked..but still puzzled whats the issue with Avro

Comment: This happened with me when my schema and that dataframe schema didn't match.